# How to connect to a tracker manually

Tags: python, p2p, bittorrent, torrent, libtorrent

I'm trying to download some torrent pieces manually.I have the tracker url. How can I connect to the tracker via python and obtain peer info.

I already created simple client using libtorrent. but my isp blocks torrent downloading. I want to undestand what's really happening under the hood.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0000.html for bittorrent specifications. BEP3 is the basic one, BEPs 15 and 23 may be relevant too, depending on the tracker.